# What is the most efficient way to test every number in a sequence against a sequence of ranges?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have two arrays.  The first sequence is a list of Doubles.  The second is a list of ranges.  The sequences and the arrays are always the same length.  What is the most efficient way to test whether every element in the first array is within the range at the same index in the second array?

Is there an efficient way to do this with a matrix library of some sort?

Snippet of what I am trying to achieve:

```
let A: [Double] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let B: [Range] = [0..2, 1..3, 2..4, 5..6, 7..8]

// TODO: Test each item in A against the range in B at the same index
// e.g. (0..2).contains(1) && (1..3).contains(2) && ... so on
```

I want to end up with a True if all items match and a false otherwise.  I need to do execute this test in a loop so I would like to find the most efficient way to do this comparison.

Comment: So, you want to make sure the first double in A is within the first range in B, the 2nd double in the 2nd range, and so on?

Comment: @HalR - Yes. That's right

Comment: It is likely that there are faster ways to compute this than the answers here using a matrix library, but you would need to reorganize your data to optimize it for the matrix operations. This would likely make other parts of your program more complicated (or require duplicating the information in different formats). Is "the most efficient" really critical here, or do you mean "pretty fast" (which the answers below are)? Making it absolutely the most efficient will also depend on how likely it is that there's a problem. Matrices will tend to compute more than necessary if failures are likely.

Comment: (Is this such an important part of your program that it's worth turning a one-line operation that is quite fast into a page of complex code that requires reorganizing your data structures?)

Comment: Its likely to be executed 100 times per second with streaming data. By design the predominant case is that 90% of the comparisons will be false.

Comment: If most of the comparisons are going to be false (and false is a stopping point for your search), then it's much less likely that a parallel solution will help you dramatically. Parallel solutions typically will over-search (since you're computing a lot of things you may not need). The setup is often not worth the parallelism. 100Hz is quite fast; I'm curious what this is tied to (it's faster than screen updates, so I assume it's not animation or similar things). Optimizations on this scale are usually about reorganizing your algorithms and data structures for your precise problem.

Comment: Of course hybrid solutions with some simd could still be very useful, but they won't be a general solution to this problem; they'll be a custom solution to your problem. At these frequencies, you really need to be thinking about things like memory locality, memory caches, and copying. You're going to need a good, honest benchmark of the full problem before you can evaluate what helps. (And of course my #1 goal would be to redesign to reduce the required frequency, or allow more partial searching. Just doing less work is always a huge win.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’d probably do something like:

```
func all(_ values: [Double], in ranges: [Range<Double>]) -> Bool {
    zip(values, ranges).allSatisfy { $1 ~= $0 }
}
```

Thus

```
let values: [Double] = [1,4,3]
let ranges: [Range<Double>] = [
    0..<3,
    1..<5,
    2..<6
]

let result = all(values, in: ranges)
```

---

Not to cloud the issue, but I’d probably make it generic, as there’s no reason it should be limited to a particular type or particular type of range:

```
func all<T, U: RangeExpression>(_ values: [T], in ranges: [U]) -> Bool where U.Bound == T {
    zip(ranges, values).allSatisfy(~=)
}
```

And as Jessy pointed out, if you flip it to use `zip(ranges, values)`, then you can use `allSatisfy(~=)`.

Comment: Do you think `lazy` would be important here? I assume `allSatisfy` should lazily iterate not eagerly.

Comment: Indeed, `lazy` is not needed. Removed.

Comment: Flip it!  `zip(ranges, values).allSatisfy(~=)`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
let doubles: [Double] = [1.0, 2.0, 4.7, 2.5, 1.1]
let ranges: [ClosedRange<Double>] = [0...2, 1...2, 1...5, -1...3, 1...2]

let result = zip(doubles, ranges).allSatisfy { $1.contains($0) }
```

`result` is a bool which should be `true` if the given doubles are in the given ranges, otherwise, it should be `false`. Keep in mind if the count of both arrays is different the result would be `false`.